# Define function that counts recursive fibonacci

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

If I write

```
     count=0;
     fib[0]:=(count=count+1; 0);
     fib[1]:=(count=count+1; 1);
     fib[n_] := (count = count+1; fib[n-2] + fib[n-1]);
```

Then I can type for example

```
     fib[5]
```

and then

```
     count
```

and I can see how many times the "fib" was used to compute fib[5].

How can I write this as a function that gives me this number immediatly? So for example f[n_] := ... ?

Comment: I'm a little unsure of your goal; what do you mean by "immediately" -- are you trying to avoid doing the recursion itself, or do you simply mean you want `f[n]` to return the `count` for `fib[n]`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to get rid of the semicolon?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think the OP means instead of typing `count` afterwards to get the number, the function `f` should spit it out. So basically, the latter of your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can just package it up into a function:

```
fibcounter[k_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Block[{fib, count = 0},
  fib[0] := (count++; 0);
  fib[1] := (count++; 1);
  fib[n_] := (count++; fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]);
  fib[k];
  count
 ]
```

If you're looking for a purely functional style, you can do:

```
Clear[fibc]
fibc[n_] := fibc[n - 1] + fibc[n - 2] + 1
fibc[0] = fibc[1] = 1
```

Reasoning: `fibc[n]` returns the number of calls needed to compute `fib[n]`, whihc is the number of calls needed for `fib[n-1]` plus the number of calls needed for `fib[n-2]` plus the original call, i.e. 1.

You can even use [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RSolve.html) to get a closed form of the result:

```
RSolve[{f[0] == f[1] == 1, f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2] + 1}, f[n], n]
(* {{f[n] -> -1 + Fibonacci[n] + LucasL[n]}} *)

Simplify[FunctionExpand[%], n ∈ Integers && n >= 0]
(* {{f[n] -> -1 + (1 - 1/Sqrt[5]) (-(2/(1 + Sqrt[5])))^n + (1 + 1/Sqrt[5]) (1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n}} *)
```

Comment: I thinkl that `RSolve` should have `f[n] == 1 + f[n - 2] + f[n - 1]`.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Daniel Do you know why `FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[n], n \[Element] Integers]` refuses to expand?   It prevents `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, Simplify@FunctionExpand[...]]` from working.

Comment: I do not know. I expected it to do something myself.